# Можно ли добавлять классы тегу script?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Можно ли добавлять классы тегу script? Например, для того, чтобы привести их в работу только в медиа-запросе

Comment: Добавлять-то можно, только на работу это абсолютно никак не повлияет

Comment: для этого медиа-запрос не поможет, только js, а имеено добавление тега скрипт во время работы, разумеется откатить назад это никак нельзя без перезагрузки страницы, если акция разовая подойдет

Answer (score 2):

- Если вам надо один раз запустить скрипт, то можно так:

  ```js
  const result = document.querySelector('#result');
  const limit = 500;

  const someFunction = () => result.innerHTML += 'You ran me';

  const onResize = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth > limit) return;
    
    someFunction();
    
    window.removeEventListener('resize', onResize);
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="result"><div>
  ```
- Если вам надо один раз запустить скрипт, но каждый раз, когда размер экрана становится меньше определённого лимита, то можно так:

  ```js
  const result = document.querySelector('#result');
  const limit = 500;
  let canRunAgain = true;

  const someFunction = () => result.innerHTML += 'You ran me';

  const onResize = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth > limit) {
      canRunAgain = true;
      return;
    };
    
    if (!canRunAgain) return;
    
    someFunction();
    
    canRunAgain = false;
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="result"><div>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1**

Для определения соответствия размеров экрана определенному `медиа запросу` из JS можно использовать метод `window.matchMedia` метод вернет объект одним из ключей которых будет `matches` булевое значение которого и будет определять соответствие.

Таким образом скрипт можно выполнять при определенном размере экрана обернув нужный функционал в условие:

```js
const mediaQuery = "screen and (max-width: 757px)"
const output = document.querySelector("#output");
const updateOutput = () => {
  const isMax757 = matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches   
  output.innerText = isMax757;
  matchMedia(mediaQuery).addEventListener("change", updateOutput, {     once: true })
  if (window.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches){

     // какой-то код для определенного mediaQuery

  }
}

updateOutput();
```

```html
<span id="output"></span>
```

Этот код лучше тестировать на весь экран, при изменении размеров до 757px будет отображено true, иначе false.

Как видно тут мы навешиваем события на изменения связанные с условием `медиа запроса`, а опция `once: true` отвечает за то чтобы после исполнения события происходила автоматическая отписка от него, тут происходит регулярная подписка/отписка, что может быть прервано при определенных условиях в коде

**Вариант 2** (предыдущий ответ)

Для того случая когда содержимое тега скрипта нужно временно запретить к исполнению

В данном случае:

- любой, кастомный тип скрипта предотвращает исполнение `type="norun"`
- содержимое скрипта заносится в переменную `scriptCode`
- далее добавляется на страницу через новый тег `<script>`,
- происходит его автоматическое исполнение

Я полагаю, что тэг скрипта с содержимым может формироваться на бэке к примеру через PHP, тогда этот ответ может иметь смысл.

```js
const scriptCode = document.getElementById('mycode').textContent
const myScript = document.createElement('script')
myScript.textContent = scriptCode
document.body.appendChild(myScript)
```

```html
<script id="mycode" type="norun">
  console.log('Hello World')
</script>
```